# I can not view logs in kibana or I can not add logs to elasticseach with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I start `kibana`, `elastiksearch` and `logstash`
I write simple server:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/test")
  public String test(){

    log.debug("test");

    return "OK";
  }
}
```

add appender:

```
<appender name="STASH" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>test.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>redditApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
  </appender>
```

When I start server - create `test.log` file with logs in JSON type.
When I call  call `/test` - in `test.log` add line:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-08-07T14:36:08.624+03:00","@version":"1","message":"test","logger_name":"com.example.logs.controllers.TestController","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000}
```

After that I want parse this file by logstash and add all logs to elasticksearch. I add confik to logstash:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:\projects\logs\*.log"
        codec => "json"
        type => "logback"
    }
}

output {
    if [type]=="logback" {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
             index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

and start logstash. It started successfull.

[image]

After that I open kibana I not understand how can I see logs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`[type]` has been deprecated. Remove it from your output:

```
output {
     elasticsearch {
         hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
         index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

EDIT: and your input. Actually, try using tags:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:\projects\logs\*.log"
        codec => "json"
        tags => ["logback"]
    }
}

output {
    if "logback" in tags {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
             index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```